# Getting time difference from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an array like this -

```
[ 'State is:1Time:2019-2-3 11:45:02',  
  'State is:1Time:2019-2-3 12:45:05',  
  'State is:1Time:2019-3-4 11:45:00',  
  'State is:2Time:2019-3-5 11:45:08',  
  'State is:2Time:2019-4-5 11:45:10',  
  'State is:2Time:2019-4-5 11:45:12', ]
```

Using Javascript, how do I check occurences by state and subtract their times. This means for example
`State 1` occurs 3 times and I want the difference in time between the first occurence `State 1` with time `2019-2-3 11:45:02`
and third occurence `State 1`  with time `2019-3-4 11:45:00`? And like so for `State 2` as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . And add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
function calculateTime() {
    var array = [ 'State is:1Time:2019-2-3 11:45:02',  
  'State is:1Time:2019-2-3 12:45:05',  
  'State is:1Time:2019-3-4 11:45:00',  
  'State is:2Time:2019-3-5 11:45:08',  
  'State is:2Time:2019-4-5 11:45:10',  
  'State is:2Time:2019-4-5 11:45:12', ];
  var previousState=0;
  var previousTime = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
  {
      var str = array[i];
  str = str.split('Time');
 var str1 = str[0].split(":");
 var str2 = str[1].split(/:{0-1}/);
 var currentState = str1[1];

 var date = new Date(str2[0].substring(1,str2[0].length));
 var currentTime = date.getTime();
 if((previousState != currentState && (i >0 )|| i ==array.length-1)  )
 {
     console.log(currentTime - previousTime);
 }
 previousState = currentState;
 previousTime = currentTime;
 }

}
```